# Need to dynamically insert a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there such a way? I've had little success in using the .innerHTML method.

Some context, I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to make a text RPG as a bit of a fun project using what I know in HTML, CSS, and Javascript... The latter of which I've had not too much experience with yet.

The function would have to modify a  element, inserting a snippet that asks for a name for a character, and the form along with a submit button... Then take what they enter and modify a JSON variable that'll essentially function as a character file.

It all has to be done client side as well, if it can be helped... Any way someone might help? Or of not give an outright solution, point me in the right direction?

Comment: You *can* use the DOM to do that, but it might be more appropriate to just have the form as part of your HTML and show or hide it using `display` as appropriate.

Comment: JavaScript can do anything with the dom. For your purpose, I totally disagree with @rninty. Generate everything with js and let the page be generated via something simple like `myRPG.init(someElement);` and it will create the whole game into that element on the page. To do this well, you'll need to learn a lot. Object Oriented programming is the key.

Comment: Well for now I'll have to go with the .show/.hide approach, but how about actually grabbing the name the player types into the form? While keeping it entirely client sided, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/HTTP_cookies) to store information on the browser, such as a player name. Example is

```
document.cookie='PlayerName = ThatOneGuy';
```

You can see more details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/HTTP_cookies

Comment: Does that really answer the question, though? And psst… [not W3Schools, please](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Development/HTTP_cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Below, I've written some simple dom manipulation, that creates a form, an input, and when the input loses focus stores whatever is in the input, into either a cookie or `localStorage`.

There are several things missing, like checking if the input actually had a value, along with zero error checking.

You can find out more about `localStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). You can find out more about cookies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

```
function init_form(){
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    var input = document.createElement('input');

    input.setAttribute('id', 'player_name');
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', ' Enter Characters Name');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');

    form.appendChild(input);
    document.appendChild(form); //or document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += form;
    input.addEventListener('blur', store_name_in_local_storage, false); 
}

function store_name_in_local_storage(){
    var name = document.getElementById('player_name');

    //check to see if browser supports local storage if it does, use it, if it doesn't use cookies
    if(!window.localStorage){
        document.cookie = 'player_name ='+ name;
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem('player_name', name);
    }
}

function get_player_name(){
    var name = '';

    //retrieve the cookie or local storage name
    if(!window.localStorage){
        name = document.cookie
    }else{
        name = localStorage.getItem('player_name');
    }
}
```

**Note about the links:** Since your new to javascript I would use the second link on `localStorage`, the first is very good documentation about how to use it, and the third is the actual specification page for the feature.

Also, I included the code for setting cookies to be thorough, not because you really need it. `localStorage` is supported all the way back to IE8 and in all the other major browsers.

If you want to check the compatibility of any javascript/html5 feature I suggest [here](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage).

Good Luck!